# Add to cart creating new product programatically

Tags: magento-1.8, product, addtocart

We have 2 buttons in product view page

1)Create - create product programtically

2)Add to cart - Add product to cart &  creating product programatically.

> Issue is we dont need to create product once click on "Add to cart"
>
> create button code

```
<button id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}"  onclick="return setproductlogin(\'<?php echo Mage::registry("current_product")->getId()?>\', event);setrequestlogin();"  >
    create
    </button>
```

> Add to cart

```
<button onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)" id="submit-editorApply-add-to-cart">
    Add to cart>
    </button>
```

> related code

```
initObservers: function() 
      { 
        if (this.config.editorEnabled) {  
           $('submit-editorApply-' + this.config.rand).observe('click', this.saveDesignBut.bindAsEventListener(this));
           $('submit-editorApply-add-to-cart').observe('click', this.submitApply.bindAsEventListener(this));             
         } 
       }, 

submitApply: function(event) 
        { 
         Event.stop(event); 
         this.option.apply(); 
         if(window.productAddToCartForm == 'undefined') { 
         var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form'); 
         } else { 
          var productAddToCartForm = window.productAddToCartForm; 
         } 
         productAddToCartForm.submit(); 

         },
```

> Update

once i remove function : `submitApply: function(event)` [see full function above ] , than Add to cart button will not create any product. but after that, we need to click on `create` button to click on `Add to cart`, otherwise `Add to cart` will not work....

> update 2

when i hide this code : `$('submit-editorApply-add-to-cart').observe('click', this.submitApply.bindAsEventListener(this));` & removed `aitcg-required` , than both features will work, but one more issue will create that once we click directly on add to cart [ without click on create] button, than in cart page, we dont see custom image :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check whether two buttons have same form functionality..so it will create an issue.

You have to divide both functionality with help of separate forms

Comment: @ Nihar S : How To Display Tooltip When Customer On Mouse Hover Add to Cart Button